# Probability of passing the exam

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

The exam consists of 5 questions. All of those 5 questions are randomly picked (without repetitions) from a pool of 41 questions.

Knowing that I know answers to 35 out of 41 questions from the pool (that is: I don't know how to solve 6 out of 41 questions), what is the propability that I will fail the exam?

*(Assume that one must answer all 5 exam questions correctly to pass).*

I haven't been introduced to propability mathematics yet, I am just curious.

---

My attempt:

Chance that first question is "good" (I know how to answer the question) is $\frac{35}{41}$.

But the chance that the second question is "good" is either $\frac{34}{40}$ or $\frac{35}{40}$ depending whether the first question was good or not.

How to tie up everything together?

Is the propabiltiy of succeeding simply:

$$p_{succ} = \frac{35}{41} \frac{34}{40} \frac{33}{39} \frac{32}{38} \frac{31}{37} = ~0.432$$

and therefore failure propability:

$$p_{fail} = 1 - p_{succ} = ~0.568$$

?

Comment: Well, you need to explain what happens with a question you don't know.  Are you sure to get it wrong?  Or is it a multiple choice test, so you'll have some probability of guessing correctly?

Comment: You're right. I assume that "good" questions (35 out of 41) are surely answered correctly, and "bad" questions (6 out of 41) are surely answered incorrectly.

Comment: In that case, you need all $5$ to be chosen from the good $35$.  There  are $\binom {35}5$ ways to choose $5$ from $35$, and $\binom {41}5$ ways to choose $5$ from $41$ so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all $5$ questions are chosen from good questions, we pass. Therefore, there are $\binom{35}{5}$ such choices. We also know that we can choose $5$ questions from $41$ questions with $\binom{41}{5}$, which is the total number of choices. Therefore, the **probability of passing** should be
$$\frac{\dbinom{35}{5}}{\dbinom{41}{5}}$$
So your answer is correct.